# Multiple alert variants following form submit

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms

I've been working to put together a rating form so that users can rate products and am looking for a way to provide the user with the appropriate feedback after submitting the form. I initially had the form redirect to another page that handled the data and echoed the responses ("Your rating has been updated.", "Your rating has been added to the database." and "Please login to submit a rating.") but don't want to redirect the user and so switched to using ajax instead.

Whilst I'm able to provide alerts to tell the user if the form has been submitted, I seem to be limited to a success or failure message and was hoping there was a way I could call the responses from the handler rather than using the default 'success' alert that I have at the moment (which itself isn't really accurate in instances where a guest attempts to submit a rating). I'm also receiving the 'success' alert twice at the moment for some reason.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Submit function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitform(){
    $.ajax({
        url:'/ratings/products/productratinghandler.php',
        type:'post',
        data:$('#ratingform').serialize(),
        success:function(){
            alert("Your rating has been added to the database.");
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Form:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<form id="ratingform" onClick="javascript: submitform()" action="/ratings/products/productratinghandler.php" method="post">
  <input type="radio" id="r1" name="rg1" value="100" <?php echo $hundred; ?>>
  <label for="r1">&#9733;</label>
  <input type="radio" id="r2" name="rg1" value="90" <?php echo $ninety; ?>>
  <label for="r2">&#9733;</label>
  <input type="radio" id="r3" name="rg1" value="80" <?php echo $eighty; ?>>
  <label for="r3">&#9733;</label>
  <input type="radio" id="r4" name="rg1" value="70" <?php echo $seventy; ?>>
  <label for="r4">&#9733;</label>
  <input type="radio" id="r5" name="rg1" value="60" <?php echo $sixty; ?>>
  <label for="r5">&#9733;</label>
  <input type="radio" id="r6" name="rg1" value="50" <?php echo $fifty; ?>>
  <label for="r6">&#9733;</label>
  <input type="radio" id="r7" name="rg1" value="40" <?php echo $forty; ?>>
  <label for="r7">&#9733;</label>
  <input type="radio" id="r8" name="rg1" value="30" <?php echo $thirty; ?>>
  <label for="r8">&#9733;</label>
  <input type="radio" id="r9" name="rg1" value="20" <?php echo $twenty; ?>>
  <label for="r9">&#9733;</label>
  <input type="radio" id="r10" name="rg1" value="10" <?php echo $ten; ?>>
  <label for="r10">&#9733;</label>
  <input type="hidden" id="username" name="username" value="<?php if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true){echo $usn;}?>">
  <input type="hidden" id="productid" name="productid" value="<?php echo $product_id ;?>">
  </form>
</div>
```

Edit 1:
Came back to this after a few days and came up with the following...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitform(){
    $.ajax({
        url:'/ratings/products/productratinghandler.php',
        type:'post',
        data:$('#ratingform').serialize(),
        success:function(data){
            alert(data);   
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

...and in my PHP handler I set each message as a variable using if/elseif/else (eg, if() {$return = "message";}) and then closed the page with 'echo json_encode($return);'.

Hope this proves useful for others...